# dojo empty numbertextbox is displaying NaN , but I dont want either defualt value to it

Tags: dojo, numbers, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a numbertextbox in Datagrid which is editable. If it is empty, it is displaying NaN, but I don't want either default value to it .
It should be as such (blank). Please, help me. How can I achieve this in dojo?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the contraints parameter like this:

```
var myNumberBox = new dijit.form.NumberTextBox({
    constraints: { pattern: "0.####" },  // The pattern that the number will be displayed or set as
    value: "",       // The starting value if a value isn't set from any other source
    required: false, // You may want to set this to true if user input is required
    placeHolder: "(blank)" // What is shown when no value is present
});
```

Whenever you get the value of the number box, you may want to pass it through parseInt(value) or parseFloat(value) first.  Also check if it's a number.

```
var value = parseFloat(myNumberBox.get("value"));
if ( isNan(value) ) {
    // Code to handle if it is NaN
}
```

For more help, go to this [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html#dijit-form-numbertextbox).

I hope this helps.